# Rasa not installing on Digital Ocean

Tags: digital-ocean, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I am trying to install rasa 2.0.0 on digital ocean. I created a directory for the bot and created a virtual environment using ubantu 20.04 and python 3.8.5. After the virtualenv is activated i ran `pip install rasa==2.0.0` as well as `pip3 install rasa==2.0.0`.
The installation goes upto tensorflow installation and killed word is appearing. It exits the process but on rasa or rasa train it doesn't execute. There were no errors too.
I have a django website serving on the ip and want this bot to serve through a different port to clients having websites. Can you please suggest how can I proceed ??

Answer (score 1):

The minimum ram for the droplets to install RASA is 4.0 due to tensorflow.